# EditText background control in dedicated editing mode

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext

I have EditText with white text and black background.
When i turn the device in landscape orientation EditText is almost hidden by another controls and special dedicated window is opened for editing. The problem is that it uses white background and white text is invisible on it. How can it be fixed?

Comment: override `onConfigurationChange()`. This will be invoked when orientation change will happen.

Comment: I don't need to override standard behaviour, but just to specify dedicated editor background color

Answer (score 2):

You could add `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` to your EditText XML-tag. This will prevent the EditText to expand in landscape-mode and should preserve the background color.

See the [documentation for imeOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aimeOptions)

Comment: Thanks! But the EditText control is almost hidden and editing is not comfortable, so it would be better to have dedicated editor, but with specified background color

Comment: Understandable, however I can't reproduce your problem. If I set the background of the EditText to e.g. black and the text-color to white (in the XML), the dedicated editor in landscape reverts the background to white, but it also reverts the text-color to the default. How is it your text-color is still white?

Comment: because of ForegroundSpannable with white color - it's syntax highlighting

Comment: I see.. you didn't mention Spannables, "normal" coloring e.g. via XML bypasses that problem. I'm not aware of an option for modifying the fullscreen editor, but if spannables are apparently preserved, what about using it for the background-color as well? Other than that I'm afraid I can't help you sorry.

Comment: Using black with BackgroundSpannable makes background of every character black so every char is visible now but the other space remain white which looks weird(

Comment: You might have to alter your ForegroundSpannable then. AFAIK the fullscreen editor is created by the system, not the host app, so there's very limited control.

Comment: You're right again. I've tried to override onDraw() but it looks like it changed nothing. Is it possible to get "dedicated editor shown/hidden" event to turn on/off spannables?

Comment: Not that I know of, but you could simply check the focus (`isFocused()`, `FocusChangedListener` etc.) of your EditText when an orientation-change happened and react accordingly (see `onConfigurationChange()` as suggested in the comments above).

Comment: Changing activity orientation does not lead to showing dedicated editor instantly, so it's not reliable approach